# Prepositions "for" and "to"

Tags: prepositions, to-infinitive, for

Which of the following would be the best sentence to use:

Some people use technology **to** search for information.

Some people use technology **for** searching information.

Comment: Both of them are perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Some people use technology **to** search *for information*.

> Some people use technology **for** searching *information*.

These two sentences don't mean the same thing.  The first one is about searching *for information*, while the second is about searching *information*.

These two, on the other hand, mean the same thing:

> Some people use technology **to** search *for information*.

> Some people use technology **for** searching *for information*.

And so do these two (as each other - not as the above):

> Some people use technology **to** search *information*.

> Some people use technology **for** searching *information*.

The pair with "for information" are more usual.

The difference in meaning is as follows.  When you search *for X*, you are trying to find that thing or those things.  When you search *X*, you already know where X is, and you are trying to find something else within X.

Here is a concrete example.  If you are searching *for* a book, you can't find the book and you are trying to find the book.  If you searching a book (without *for* in front), you already have the book and you are trying to find something within the book.

In practice, "searching for information" and "searching information" often amount to the same thing - you have a vast amount of information or data, and you are searching for some specific information within the wider collection of information - so you are both searching information *and* searching *for* information.

If you are searching for a particular file on your disk, you are both searching your files and also searching for a file.

Generally, if in doubt (where either could be used), it is more idiomatic to say "search for".

Of these sentences:

> Some people use technology **to** search *for information.*

> Some people use technology **for** searching *for information*.

The first reads better, but both are correct.